# Is the css attribute !important a hack?

Tags: css

I have been forced to use `!important` in css. There is probably another way to get this done, but I am doing it because I only want a specific subset of an already styled class to have a different style. The situation is with jQuery's datepicker. In datepicker, I am setting certain days to have different priority colors. This end result is that the `td` element holding the `<a>` which holds the date gets the class name

```
.date-priority > a
{
 background: url("") red;
 border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

However, this change gets overridden because there is a more specific rule for that anchor tag, it specifically has a class on it. I do not want to change all elements with that class, only to override a few of them. So, I decided to use `!important` in the previous definition

```
.date-priority > a
{
 background: url("") red !important;
 border: 1px solid yellow !important;
}
```

It works. But it just does not seem to be best practice. Is using `!important` a hack in general, and more specifically in this instance?

HTML:

```
<td onclick="
 DP_jQuery_1348602012259.datepicker._selectDay('#date',8,2012, this);
 return false;" 
 title="Available" class=" ui-datepicker-week-end date-priority">
  <a href="#" class="ui-state-default">29</a>
</td>
```

Comment: In a way yes and no. I personally always try and find another way, as once its done... its a dark path. Also why empty URL on background?

Comment: No, it's perfectly legal, however it's typically frowned upon and used only as a last resort.

Comment: Definitely a last resort here. The blank URL is to overwrite a background url that datepicker uses.

Comment: Can you post your HTML so I can see if there is n alternative?

Comment: @David - Do you realize how large the html for jquery's datepicker is? There is nothing fancy that I am doing to it. Pretty standard stuff. Let me see if I can localize a snippet.

Comment: @TravisJ - I realise that, but surely a example of the table row would suffice?

Comment: @TravisJ - I see the issue now, however, the background url('') will be overwritten just by using background again, as seen: http://jsfiddle.net/RT8M8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the case, just add a separate rule for those elements:

```
.date-priority > a,.date-priority > a.className {
 background: url("") red;
 border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/rCyjV/**

The only reason `!important` is frowned upon is because it makes future additions to the CSS possibly frustrating.

Comment: Brilliant, this worked great. Thanks for pointing out to me that it is possible to be more specific than a direct class label :)

Comment: Specificity isn't that complicated. I suggest you skim this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 2):

Short anwser: no.

Long answer: `!important` is thought specifically for situations where you don't want a rule to be overridden by successive declarations. In addition, the "weight" assigned to the selectors (most specific = most important) is not always the behavior that a developer wants.

From [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules):

> Both author and user style sheets may contain "!important"
>   declarations, and user "!important" rules override author "!important"
>   rules. This CSS feature improves accessibility of documents by giving
>   users with special requirements (large fonts, color combinations,
>   etc.) control over presentation.

So definitely it's not a hack :-)